# Interaction behaviour not being called with ListBox's ItemSource binding

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my first foray into WPF and I've been trying to follow MVVM closely to get things right. The context here is that I've got a view that should display different sets of messages, all of which are stored in `ObservableCollection<T>`.

This is the code in my View (it's a UserControl that's hosted by a different view so I can navigate between different views at runtime)

The "i" namespace is `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"`

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:ScrollOnNewItemBehaviour />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="entities:DisplayedUserMessage">
            <!-- Removed for brevity -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is the code for the behaviour (pieced together from other SO questions I was browsing while getting to grips with the concept):

```cs
public sealed class ScrollOnNewItemBehaviour : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.Unloaded += OnUnLoaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= OnUnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var incc = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (incc == null) return;

        incc.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnUnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var incc = AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (incc == null) return;

        incc.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            var border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(AssociatedObject, 0);
            var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);

            // Only scroll when we're scrolled to the bottom of the listbox
            if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
            {
                scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here is where my specific issue comes up- the *binding* works just fine. When I change `_selectedChannel` (I've removed irrelevant code from the ViewModel below) the view updates with the new messages (`_messages` is a dictionary that holds the various ObservableCollection instances) and when I add new messages to them, the UI updates as well.

The problem is that at no point does the behaviour I've registered to the ListBox get triggered, which is a bit of an issue since I'm relying on it to keep things scrolled. My best guess was that maybe it doesn't support a bound ItemSource and the fact that the ItemSource is initially null (the dictionary will be populated asynchronously so there is no default set) means that it doesn't get registered properly/needs to be re-registered every time the binding updates?

```cs
public MessagesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<DisplayedUserMessage> _displayedMessages;
    private Channel _selectedChannel;

    public IList<DisplayedUserMessage> Messages
    {
        get
        {
            return _displayedMessages;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_displayedMessages == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _displayedMessages = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Channel SelectedChannel
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedChannel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedChannel == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _selectedChannel = value;
            Messages = _messages[_selectedChannel.Id];
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The behaviour works if it gets executed (I've verified that it doesn't with breakpoints), so if anyone has an idea regarding what I should change to make this work with changing ItemSources, please let me know!

Comment: In OnLoaded, what happens at the line `if (incc == null) return;`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt- I feel silly for not noticing that! OnLoaded is only called once and since the ItemSource starts out null, the event handler is never registered. 
Unfortunately that still begs the question- is it possible to reload the behaviour every time the binding updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of `AssociatedObject.DataContext` and wait for the `Messages` property to change to a valid value.

Or you initialize `Messages` with an empty collection and once the items are created, add them to `Messages` (this would raise the `CollectionChanged` for each item added).

A third solution is to subscribe to the [`ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.itemschanged?view=netframework-4.8) event. It is raised whenever the `ItemsControl.Items` property or the collection changes.

You can use this event instead of relying on the `ItemsSource` binding source to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. You also don't need to require the `DataContext` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
This will make your behavior more generic and reusable as it can now work with any `ItemsControl`.
This means listening to `ItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged` is equal to `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged`:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var itemsControl = AssociatedObject as ItemsControl;
    if (itemsControl == null) return;

    itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
  {
    var border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(AssociatedObject, 0);
    var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);

    // Only scroll when we're scrolled to the bottom of the listbox
    if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
    {
      scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you! I was hunting around for a different event to hook up to and ItemContainerGenerator didn't even cross my mind as a likely option. I ended up going with the 3rd solution and it works exactly as intended.